# Error npm install concurrently lite-server typescript

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm-install

I'm trying to fix the npm start trouble on angular's quick start so I tried to install these dependencies. Unfortunately I'm encountering these error messages:

```
$ sudo npm install -g concurrently lite-server typescript
npm WARN deprecated tough-cookie@2.2.2: ReDoS vulnerability parsing Set-Cookie https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/130
npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "concurrently" "lite-server" "typescript"
npm ERR! node v6.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8

npm ERR! uid must be an unsigned int
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "concurrently" "lite-server" "typescript"
npm ERR! node v6.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8

[14 - 16 of this repeatedly appears]

npm ERR! uid must be an unsigned int
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/username/npm-debug.log
```

I don't know what this means since I'm just a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reinstall node.js package 
[node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

It solves the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways to solve this issue. It has to do with permissions.
Listed below is summary of both solutions:

Solution A:

(1) Create npm-global directory under /Users// as /Users//npm-global

(2) npm config set prefix /Users//npm-global

(3) Add export PATH=/Users//npm-global/bin:$PATH to ~/.profile

(4) source ~/.profile

(5) If you don't want to do steps (3) & (4) add the export comment to ~/.bash_profile

or

Solution B:

(1) sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/

Follow the link https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions for more details